# Is "homeschooling curriculum" an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning

Is "homeschooling curriculum" an oxymoron?

The definition seems to imply it, so how do you refer to the material in the curriculum instead of the curriculum itself?

> 2. (Education) a list of all the courses of study offered by a school or college

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Curriculum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/curriculum) can also mean, more generally

> the subjects studied in a school, college, etc. and what each subject includes:

This would apply to subjects studied at home, as well, without their being divvied up in courses.

The chief use I have seen is commercial offerings of curriculums that a parent can follow to cover subjects.